# IOS 8, Link on mobile device using construct2 caus the application to crash and close

Tags: html, error-handling, client-side, construct-2

i would like to know if there is a way, to monitor IOS 8 errors on a mobile web site.
Our site is a game site, and we are using construct2 as a game platform.
by pressing a link(js - location.href), in my construct2, the mobile site crash and close (without any error report/handling).

how can i catch the error?
thank you
Ariel